# wso2 Identity Server - How to Change the :9443/commonauth endpoint - remove port

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have put the Identity server behind a reverse proxy with apache changing the default port to default HTTPS (to allow access without our internal network), I have then modified the XML files to remove the {port} from the endpoints, BUT the /commonauth endpoint is still being sent in SAML requests with the port as the assertionURL/return url?

How do I change this? is it in any configs?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `proxyPort="443"` attribute to the HTTPS connector element at the `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`

Comment: Thanks this works but I am now having my /samlsso endpoint redirecting me to a localhost login script, I cannot seem to work out what is doing this, could it be the apachesetup?

Comment: Set the "MgtHostName" value to your hostname at `repository/conf/carbon.xml`

Comment: I had that there and also updated ProxyPath within catalina-server.xml and this worked. Thanks again